# Publish NPM package from inside docker container

Tags: node.js, git, docker, npm

I am desperately trying to publish my NPM package to our NPM repo.
I keep getting an error stating that my working directory is not clean and I can't get my head around it.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12

ARG VERSION

COPY .npmrc /root/.npmrc
COPY .gitconfig /root/.gitconfig
COPY .git-credentials /root/.git-credentials

WORKDIR /home/node/app/

COPY package.json package.json

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run release:testless -- ${VERSION}
```

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "npm run prepare:util",
    "prepare:util": "npm explore vl-ui-util -- npm run install:copy",
    "test": "wct -l chrome,firefox --npm",
    "release": "npm run release:prepare && np",
    "release:prepare": "npm run release:prepare:build",
    "release:prepare:build": "npm run build",
    "release:prepare:commit": "git add -f vl-map.js && git commit --amend --no-edit && git pull",
    "release:testless": "npm run release:prepare && np --yolo",
    "demo": "npm run dev",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm:bundle:watch\" \"http-server\"",
    "build": "npm run bundle:build",
    "bundle:watch": "rollup --config rollup.config.js --watch",
    "bundle:build": "rollup --config rollup.config.js"
  }
```

This results in:

```
npm ERR! Git working directory not clean.
```

Comment: Well you've copied *everything* in, apparently including your `.git/` directory, then built some new files in there. Maybe look at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file

Comment: I wouldn’t put this in my Dockerfile.  If I have some change that I’ve validated locally, and I’m trying to build a Docker image to test it before deploying for real, I don’t want my not-fully-tested code to be published to NPM.  I also don’t want people to `docker cp` valid GitHub credentials out of my built image.  Run this outside of Docker.

Comment: @jonrsharpe if I don't copy in my .git folder, I cannot perform any git operations inside the container since it will not be recognized as a git repo. AT David, it is run on Bamboo which does not have a node environment, so it has to be built inside a container with Node environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by cloning inside the container instead of letting Bamboo do the clone and copy all my source files into the container.